# Is it possible to make windows games using Havok's Project Anarchy?

Tags: havok

I'm interrested in Havok's Project Anarchy as I plan to learn how to make 3D Games, so I've done some research and it seems focused on mobile platforms.

So before I engage myself I would like to know if it is possible to make PC Windows games with It since it is not explicitly mentionned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [features page](http://www.projectanarchy.com/features). Under "Platform Comparison" it has an entry for `Win32/64`. For `Project Anarchy Free` this is not available, but for `"Pro" Package` it is available.

Therefore, yes, it is possible to make a PC game with it -- provided you have the pro version.

How much is the pro version? Based on the [FAQ](http://www.projectanarchy.com/faq):

> How much does it cost?
>   For commercial licenses on additional platforms (beyond iOS, Android, and Tizen) you are looking at a cost relative to a small studio of about 5-10 game developers using Unity.

That's on the order of $2k-$4k.

Answer (score 2):

Licensing for Project Anarchy has changed since this question was asked/answered.
You can now get a PC exporter license, from the [updated FAQ](http://www.projectanarchy.com/faq):

> PC Exporter for Project Anarchy allows deployment to PC at a cost of $499 per seat.